# Removing post in center of two-car garage (20ft span)

Tags: garage, removal, post, support

I have a two-story house with a two-car garage under two bedrooms. The two bedrooms have a non-load bearing wall between them and the garage has a 6x10 beam underneath with a supporting post.

I want to take out the post, by bracing or sandwiching the existing beam with LVLs on either side using through-bolts and end posts. The span is including supporting end-posts 247".

how many LVLs do I need and what height of LVLS? Can I use one 1.75" x 11.75" on either side or do I need more?

Comment: Get a structural engineer to check this out.

Comment: @jsotola Wouldn’t you be liable for all the electrical questions on this site too. If you don’t use a licensed electrician then you could be liable if someone gets electrocuted. You should add that to all the electrical questions on this SE site too.

Comment: @LeeSam you are absolutely right ... what I said, need not be said ... deleted my comment

Comment: @johan Other than beam size for strength, you have a few other things to think about: 1) deflection due to longer beam span, 2) is the end column adequate, as the load has doubled, and 3) is the foundation adequate to support the column. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try one LVL and if it collapses, then rebuild the floor and use two.

It really depends on how much stuff you have in the room above and how solid you want the floor to be. Do you care if the floor bounces when you jump up and down?

I doubt that a 20 foot wall is not load bearing. What is holding up the roof? If you go into the attic, are there joists tied to the wall header?

Answer (score -2):

Your 6x10 Standard grade SPF spanning 10’ will support about 800 - 850 plf.

Two 1 3/4” x 11 7/8” lvl 20’ long will support 400 plf.

You’ll need two on each side of your 6x10 beam.

Comment: Can you provide calculation to backup your call? Note that the change from two continuous span to single span has increased strength demand by N-folds.

Comment: @r13 Wow, I’m crushed that nobody understood my calculations. Gee, you don’t think these people are vindictive do you?

Comment: Not sure why all the downvotes.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Is 4 a record?

Comment: Dunno if it's a record, but it's pretty high nonetheless... I guess people don't know you...

Comment: upgrade  6x10  by another 6x12 of engineered wood,  that sounds about right, assuming the engineered wood is amost twice as strong as natural wood.

Comment: 'you need two on each side' = four altogether?

Comment: @Tim Exactly...did you read the last line of my answer?